# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android, gradle

So I'm following the official documentation to add the Material Components library to my project https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

But it throws me the following error 
"Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1"

I've tried installing the repository and sync project that Android Studio suggest to no avail.

My project config

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the app config

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "mlluell.eftremp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'

//imatges recyclerview
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'

// FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'

// FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'

// FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.0'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Those instructions do not appear to be correct, at least at the moment. If you visit https://maven.google.com in a Web browser, that artifact is not among those listed, AFAICT. I believe that this repository will be debuted more officially at Google I|O this coming week; you might want to hold off trying to use it until then.

Comment: This is another answer if you got the issue in to use of material library https://stackoverflow.com/a/53693942/4395804

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thought I'd share what fixed this for me now that I|O has started.

I had about the same initial setup as you. To get it working I had to change the following:

- compileSdkVersion to `'android-P'`
- Support Libraries to `'28.0.0-alpha1'`
- include `api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'` in the dependencies block.
- SDK Platform update - Android P Preview (latest)
- targetSdkVersion `'P'`

I then did the ritualistic 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' and rebuilt the project for good measure.

Comment: you save me a ton of time

Comment: Even if you compile with `'android-P'`, you can still maintain compatibility with older devices by setting the `minSdkVersion`. You will just have to make sure that you take care of the few new components that haven't been back ported yet

Comment: @ImArtVandalay, how were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @parekhkruti26: Just trial and error. But I did later come across [this as confirmation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-codelabs/blob/master/java/shrine/app/build.gradle) by way of the 2018 I/O Material Components Developer tutorials.

Comment: Does this allow you to use the components for Android 7/8/9?

Answer (score 34):

Instead of:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Use:

```
   implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.1.0-alpha05'
```

And it works.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Any idea why it works one way and not the other?

Comment: @DanishKhan not sure to be honest, I guess in case of alpha versions it can´t find them with the standard format, my guess this is a repository issue.

Comment: @Lancelot properly added the missing _0_ between _alpha_ and the number: ´version: '1.1.0-alpha05' ´
The current version is 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01'

Answer (score 7):

**FOR ANDROIDX USERS:**

You can implement as follows:

***AndroidX:***

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

***Old build artifact users can use the following implementation:***

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:[Enter Design library version here]'
```

Use that version without square brackets.
You can find design library version via this link : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/design/28.0.0

Answer (score 5):

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'`
```

Comment: Add some comments that would explain what you've done.

Comment: <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

Answer (score 4):

Well that happened to me an hour ago...
I always suggest check the most basic issues for example:

Go to >> Gradle `module.app`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

When you have a syntax's error; `Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:x.x.x` appears.

Have a great day!

Comment: When you have a syntax's error; That was the catch. A space wasted my time.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your gradle.properties enabled AndroidX using the following Line:

```
android.useAndroidX = true
```

If not added then add this line and sync project again

[Visit For More Details](https://answerdone.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For **androidx** users:
My problem got solved by just updating all the dependencies with latest version. It got solved in just 2 minutes. My previous version was 1.0.2 and showed same error. I just clicked on '**Show in Project Structure dialog**' which appeared below the error. From there you will get options to update dependencies to latest version. For users other than androidx might be the same soution works.