# Can't compile new Material library in Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, material-design

I can't add the new Material Design library.
When I add `compile 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'` and I sync the project, I get this two errors:

```
error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
error: resource android:attr/ttcindex not found.
```

My `build.gradle`:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rockthesport.com.pruebasmaterial"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: Build.gradle posted

Comment: Maybe you should look this post => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193885/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-materialmaterial1-0-0-alpha1/50243620

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Comment: Follow this answer for proper solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/53693942/4395804

Answer (score 2):

To use the new [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) `'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'` you have to use

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 'android-P'

        defaultConfig {
            targetSdkVersion 'P'
        }
        ...
    }
```