# Load Material in Gradle - Failed downloading 'android-P'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, material-design

i am really new to Android Studio.

I would like to add the **Material** dependency to my project but while `sync` my gradle file I get an error message.

This thread ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344388/cant-compile-new-material-library-in-gradle)) told me to use `compileSdkVersion 'android-P'` but this results in android studio telling me to download `android-P`which it fails to do, when i click on download (... android-P not avaliable for download..).

So I went back to trying it as described on the material homepage [get started](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/).

Below you can my find my according code and error message:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chris.doghelper"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And Error Message:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-24:19 to override.
```

Do you have a fix for my problem?

Comment: I think you can solve your Problem when you use AndroidX libraries instead of Android Support Libraries.

Comment: So, did you resolve your problem right?

Comment: It did. I just accepted your answer Prince! :) thanks!

Comment: Oh, That's great. Happy to know that you solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using the new Material library with the legacy Support Library. You have to migrate `android.support` to `androidx` in order to use `com.google.android.material`.

If you don't want to switch over to the new `androidx` and `com.google.android.material` packages yet, you can use Material Components via the `com.android.support:design:28.0.0` dependency.

Follow [Link1](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/193#issuecomment-418463394) and [Link2](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

To switch androidX follow this [Link3](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

I went to more deeper and I got it for you.

It will definitely help you.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hey Prince!

The answer you provided that I should follow is the same as the one i posted right? What do you want me to change in my code, since I tried to do it as in the tutorial in the first place.. thanks!

Comment: Hey chris, try this one.

Comment: Hey Prince. I am sorry, but I do not know how to switch over to androix.. But as you said I can use the material compents via the design:28.0.0 dependency. That would work for me aswell, since I already have that implemented. But from my perspective I can not use material compents via the design:28.0.0 dependency, e.g. I can not use material tabs in any xml file.  The getting started link is exactly what I am trying to do aswell btw :(

Comment: Yes to use material component from support library but if you need to use from material library you need to switch androidX. For that follow this link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: So, if you dont want to go in more deeper remove material library and use material component from support library or switch to android X.