# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material.material:1.0

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I've been trying to get the floatingActionButton to work but it seems it's not working due to my gradle dependencies, the gradle code is shown below please i need some help on this,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "-------------"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material.material:1.0.0-alpha1;'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

Comment: This might help you to resolve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193885/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-materialmaterial1-0-0-alpha1

Comment: Share your project gradle.

Comment: you need to migrate to andoridx in order to use material library, either use 28.0.3 version of design support library.

Comment: change your line to `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1`

Comment: @KaranMer please how should i do this? i'm taking a course and i need it

Comment: @MicahTimileyin **Refactor** --> **migrate to android x**

Comment: right click on your app module, select refactor and select migrate to andoridx option

Comment: you would need to additional settings to support jetifier, check this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in your dependency definition. Remove semi-colon at end and replace `.` with `:` between `com.google.android.material` and `material:1.0.0-alpha1`

So all together, change

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material.material:1.0.0-alpha1;'
```

To

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
```